# Group elements in a list by range Scala

Tags: list, scala

Considering the following List in Scala :

`List(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 17, 23, 24, 25)`

I want to get the output

```
List(List(4,8), List(12,14), List(17), List(23,25))
```

I have this answer [Scala List function for grouping consecutive identical elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761386/scala-list-function-for-grouping-consecutive-identical-elements)

But it is working for grouping identical elements in the same List.

How to extend this solution to resolve my current problem?

I have tried this code

```
def sliceByRange[A <% Int](s: List[A]): List[List[A]] = s match {
      case Nil => Nil
     case x :: xs1 =
    val (first, rest) = s.span(y => y - x == 1)
    first :: sliceByRange(rest)
    }
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What is the pattern rule for grouping numbers?

Comment: Grouping consecutive numbers in the same List

Comment: What problems did you run into when you have implemented it yourself?

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I got it... xD

Comment: A little bit trickier case than usual, no solutions at all after 20 mins :)

Comment: @syl you should edit the question with this info (the code you tried and the error it causes), not as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tail-recursive solution

### Code

Note that you could also use `List[(Int,Int)]` as result type instead of `List[List[Int]]`. This would reflect the fact that the result is a `List` of ranges more appropriately. Of course then you couldn't turn `List(x,x)` into `List(x)` for singleton ranges. But I expect that this will come back to bite you later anyway.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

@tailrec
def split(in: List[Int], acc: List[List[Int]] = Nil): List[List[Int]] = (in,acc) match {
  case (Nil,a) => a.map(_.reverse).reverse
  case (n :: tail, (last :: t) :: tt) if n == last + 1 => split(tail, (n :: t) :: tt)
  case (n :: tail, a ) => split(tail, (n :: n :: Nil) :: a)
}

val result = split(List(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 17, 23, 24, 25))
println(result)

println("removing duplicates:")
println(result.map{
  case List(x,y) if x == y => List(x)
  case l => l
})
```

### Output

```
List(List(4, 8), List(12, 14), List(17, 17), List(23, 25))
removing duplicates:
List(List(4, 8), List(12, 14), List(17), List(23, 25))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as shown: `scala> split(List(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 17, 23, 24, 25))
res2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(4, 8), List(12, 12), List(13, 13), List(14, 14), List(17, 17), List(23, 23), List(24, 24), List(25, 25))` Am I missing something?

Comment: @Toby Thanks, I introduced a bug on a later edit. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example:

```
val myList = List(4, 5, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 17, 23, 24, 25)

def partition(list: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int]) = {
    val listPlusOne = (list.head - 1 :: list) // List(1,2,5) => List(0, 1, 2, 5)
    val zipped = list zip listPlusOne // zip List(1,2,5) with List(0, 1, 2, 5) => List((1,0), (2,1), (5,2))

    val (a, b) = zipped span { case (a, b) => b + 1 == a } // (List((1,0), (2,1)), List((5,2)))
    (a.map(_._1), b.map(_._1)) // (List(1, 2),List(5))
}

def group(list: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = list match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case _ =>
        val (a, b) = partition(list)
        val listA =  List(List(a.head, a.last).distinct) // remove middle numbers..
        val listB = if (b.isEmpty) Nil else group(b)
        listA ++ listB
}

println(group(myList))
```

A bit more complicated, but it works...

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing the answer of the question you referenced:

```
def split(list: List[Int]) : List[List[Int]] = list match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case h::t =>
    val segment = list.zipWithIndex.takeWhile { case (v, i) => v == h+i }.map(_._1)
    List(h, segment.last).distinct :: split(list drop segment.length)
}
```

Using `zipWithIndex` to check for each element whether it's exactly the "next" integer (number should increase "together" with the index). Then - taking only the "boundaries" of the segment and recursively moving on to the rest of the list.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
def sliceByRange(items: List[Int]) =
  items.sorted.foldLeft(Nil: List[List[Int]]) {
    case (initRanges :+ (head :: Nil), next) if head == next - 1 =>
      initRanges :+ (head :: next :: Nil) // append element to the last range
    case (initRanges :+ (head :: last :: Nil), next) if last == next - 1 =>
      initRanges :+ (head :: next :: Nil) // replace last range
    case (ranges, next) =>
      ranges :+ (next :: Nil) // add new range
  }
```

Usage:

```
sliceByRange(List(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 19))
// List(List(1, 3), List(5), List(8, 9), List(12, 14), List(19))
```

If you wish to keep middle values you can use the following example:

```
def makeSegments(items: List[Int]) =
  items.sorted.foldLeft(Nil: List[List[Int]]) {
    case (initSegments :+ lastSegment, next) if lastSegment.last == next - 1 =>
      initSegments :+ (lastSegment :+ next)
    case (segments, next) =>
      segments :+ (next :: Nil)
  }
```

Usage:

```
makeSegments(List(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 19))
// List(List(1, 2, 3), List(5), List(8, 9), List(12, 13, 14), List(19))
```

When range size at least 3 elements:

```
def sliceByRange3elements(items: List[Int]) =
  items.sorted.foldLeft(Nil: List[List[Int]]) {
    case (initRanges :+ (head :: last :: Nil), next) if last == next - 1 =>
      initRanges :+ (head :: next :: Nil) // replace last range
    case (initRanges :+ (ll :: Nil) :+ (l :: Nil), next) if ll == next - 2 && l == next - 1 =>
      initRanges :+ (ll :: next :: Nil) // make new range
    case (ranges, next) =>
      ranges :+ (next :: Nil)
  }
```

Usage (note that (8,9) are not range now):

```
sliceByRange3elements(List(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 19))
// List(List(1, 3), List(5), List(8), List(9), List(12, 14), List(19))
```

You can define `printRanges` method to more visual output:

```
def printRanges(ranges: List[List[Int]]) =
  ranges.map({
    case head :: Nil => head.toString
    case head :: last :: Nil => s"$head-$last"
    case _ => ""
  }).mkString(",")

printRanges(
  sliceByRange(List(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 19)))
// 1-3,5,8-9,12-14,19

printRanges(
  sliceByRange3elements(List(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 19)))
// 1-3,5,8,9,12-14,19
```